# Is it possible to see the script generated from a pgAdmin import job?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I was having trouble importing a csv, so I created a table without loading and went through the pgAdmin 4 importer - which worked!  But now I want to see what it did differently to make it work.  Is there a way to see the script behind the import job?

Thanks!

Comment: ok  looks like you can see the command from the 'process watcher' - if you click on more detail when the job status pops up.  But I still cannot copy the 'FROM 'myfile' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE ''''; into the sql script - I get ERROR:  COPY quote must be a single one-byte character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `pgAdmin4.log`, You might get the complete command executed by pgAdmin4 in the log file itself.